# FastCGI URL cannot contain spaces

Tags: apache, fastcgi, hhvm

I read about HHVM/Hack and thought that I would look into that. Especially static typing is something that I have longed for in PHP for ages. I compiled HHVM from source, since the binary for Fedora is very outdated. I then setup apache to route php requests through FastCGI and it seamed to work just fine. That is until I tried accessing a script within a sub-folder that contained spaces. For some reason whenever the URI contains something like localhost/sub%20folder/file.php, I get an 404 message while localhost/sub-folder/file.php is working just fine. My apache line for fastcgi looks like the below

> ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/$1"

I have also tried using

> ProxyPass / fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/

but I got the same problem. My guess is that I somehow have to remove the added %20 from the path, but not sure how to do this.